# XCode server build log location on disk

Tags: xcode, xserver, osx-server

We use bots to build our iOS apps using the X server.

A few days ago, after the release of iOS 8, there were updates for Xcode, OSX and server and after installing the updates I am unable to find the log. It seems like Apple moved it to a different location?

Before these updates the log file was located at;
/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Latest/output/build.log

I had a look but there is no /Library/Server/Xcode folder anymore?

The reason I would like to view these logs is because a python script is monitoring them and if there is a problem building notifying me of the problem by coloring a Philips hue light.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally forgot to post the result of my search.
I did find a solution to the problem.

Apple has a JSON service which you can contact to get the build logs.
You can find it here;
https://**1.2.3.4**/xcode/api/integrations/ *(**1.2.3.4** is the ip of your xcode server)*

You can either view it with your browser or write a script to poll the JSON feed and process it.

You might get a SSL security warning in your browser if your SSL connection has no certificate.

Regards,

Robert